# EJS doesn't scape

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ejs

I want to fill a table with EJS and I have this

```
<% User.find(function(err, users){
                if (err){res.send(err);}
                if (users){ 
                    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){ %>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <%= users[i].identif  %> </td>
                            <td> <%= users[i].tipo_identif  %> </td>
                            <td> <%= users[i].nombres  %> </td>
                            <td> <%= users[i].apellidos  %> </td>
                            <td> <%= users[i].rol  %> </td>
                            <td> <%= users[i].correo  %> </td>
                            <td> <%= users[i].carrera  %> </td>
                            <td> <%= users[i].password  %> </td>
                            <td> <button type='button' class='btn btn-default editar-usuario' id='"+registro.identif+"'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' aria-hidden='true'></span></button> </td>
                            <td> <button type='button' class='btn btn-default eliminar-usuario' id='"+registro.identif+"'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' aria-hidden='true'></span></button> </td>
                        </tr>
            <% }}}); %>
```

The content between tr doesn't appear, the table wont poblate. I used console.log to check if users is empty and it returned an array.

Answer (score 0):

The ejs-template does not work with nested callbacks.

You need to first collect all the data, and only then call ejs-template.

Comment: How can I do that?